# How to evaluate a condition number for a function of several variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

I'm trying to get the condition number of a multivariate function $f(a,b,c)$ to see if it is stable. I am reading the information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Several_variables).

[image]

I know how to do it for a $1$-dimensional function. But for a multivariate one, I am not sure how. Also how do I even get the Jacobian because there is only 1 function here. Wouldn't that mean the Jacobian is a $1 \times 3$ matrix?

Comment: Provided that "there is only 1 function here" means that the function $f$ is a scalar function, then simply compute the Jacobian as if $f$ was a 1-component vector function (that is, you get the gradient of f).

Comment: Doesnt that give you a column vector. Doesn't jaccobian need to be a square matrix?

Comment: [Why should it be square?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant)

Comment: Actually since its really like [f(a,b,c)] which is a 1 by 1 vector. The jaccobian will be a row vector (1 by 3). Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: Also, does ||f(a,b,c)|| mean the biggest value in magnitude that the function can be for any inputs? Also what would ||x|| be?

Comment: Everything in the expression for the condition number is evaluated at a *single* point $x=(a,b,c)$. Norm of a scalar is (usually) simply its absolute value.

Comment: I'm still pretty confused. I know the ||J|| becomes a 1 by 3 vector. I don't understand what the final equation looks like. Is ||f(x)|| just the absolute value of the function f(a,b,c)? And ||x|| just (|a|,|b|,|c|)?

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a scalar differentiable function, then the condition number of $f$ at $x^*=(x_1^*,\ldots,x_n^*)$ is given by
$$
\frac{\|J(x^*)\|}{|f(x^*)| / \|x^*\|} = \frac{\|x^*\| \|J(x^*)\|}{|f(x^*)|}
$$
Assuming you choose $L_2$ norm:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{
\sum_{i=1}^n (f'_{x_i})^2(x_1^*,\ldots,x_n^*)
}}{|f(x_1^*,\ldots,x_n^*)| / \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^*)^2}} =
\frac{ 
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^*)^2} \;
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (f'_{x_i})^2(x_1^*,\ldots,x_n^*)}}{|f(x_1^*,\ldots,x_n^*)|}
$$

Comment: Is there a textbook covering such topics?